# Should I use ‘mich’ or ‘sich’ in this infinitive construction?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, reflexive

In my German homework, I’m trying to say

> I like to stay in a hotel where there is a spa in order to relax.

Would I say *um **sich** zu entspannen* or *um **mich** zu entspannen?*
Or am I completely wrong and is none of this grammatically right?

The full sentence is

> Ich übernachte gern in einem Hotel, wo es ein Spa gibt, um sich/mich zu entspannen.

Comment: I added the missing commas in your example. Also, I would use *in dem* in place of *wo* — the latter sounds rather colloquial while I would use the former in written contexts. I should note that I’m from the South where *wo* is commonly used in speech; in the North it immediately marks me as a southerner because everybody would use *in dem.*

Comment: Would the structure of the sentence be the same? Would it just be 'Ich übernachte gern in einem Hotel, dem es ein Spa gibt.' Or is there a different construction?

Comment: Same construction: ‘Ich übernachte gerne in einem Hotel, **in** dem es ein Spa gibt.’

Comment: Neither of them sounds good. How about: "Ich übernachte gern in einem Hotel, wo es ein Spa **zum Entspannen** gibt." — Alternatively, "...wo man sich entspannen kann" or "...wo ich mich entspannen kann".

Answer (score 6):

You can say both and they give the sentence a slightly different nuance.

If you use *mich* then it is important to you that it is a spa where *you* yourself can relax. Some spas may not meet the definition because *you* cannot relax there.

> I like to stay in a hotel where there is a spa that **I** can relax in.

If you use *sich* then the spa need only be relaxing to *some people;* akin to using *one* in an English translation:

> I like to stay in a hotel where there is a spa that **one** can relax in.

Comment: Well, you may hear something like that, but it is awkward. Usually, using "sich" in a dependent sentence like in your example would require a suitable subject (Ich, jemand, Leute) to be mentioned in the main phrase. In your phrase, your subject is "Ich", and using then "sich" in the dependent sentence may technically be possible, but it leaves a queer impression. I would not do this (except in very informal oral language).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Does it now? In my opinion this is not the case.